# Need a simple pixel shader code which just draws an input texture to the screen (viewport)

Tags: c#, xna, shader

I need a simple shader code to use with my XNA application which just draws a given texture to the screen .. Essentially, I'm trying to do post processing, but my aim here is to not apply any post processing effect, but to just display the texture as itself ..

I tried the following pixel shader code but I'm getting some problem (explained below):

```
sampler textureSampler;

float4 PostProcessingPS(float2 texCoord: TEXCOORD0, float4 Position : POSITION0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 color = tex2D(textureSampler,texCoord);
    return color;
}

technique PostProcessingEffect
{
    pass Pass1
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PostProcessingPS();
    }
}
```

The issue I'm getting is that the *entire* texture is not drawn .. Only the borders are being drawn for some reason ?! And even regarding the borders, I'm not sure if they are being drawn properly .. I'm just saying they are being drawn because the pixel values there change as the scene itself changes ..

This is what it should be like:
[image]

And this is what I see:
[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: I'd recommend using PIX (in the DirectX SDK) to determine what is wrong with your scene. It looks like you've either got wireframe rendering turned on, or there is something wrong with your model or transforms or vertex shader.

Comment: I don't know what your position parameter code is for, but the rest of your code would help.  Try returning blue as a static color to make sure your shader is being used, then try using your texture coordinates to return a color without using the texture to help diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice is to just display the texture in your draw code. Why exactly can't you do this in the application instead of in the pixel shader?

If you REALLY want to do the pixel shader, you'll need to give more code. What is drawn is dependent on the texture coordinates, so i would need to see your draw code to answer this.

Answer (score 0):

How are you drawing the full-screen quad? You may have the vertex winding opposite to the current cull mode so the triangles are being backface culled. You can check this by using GraphicsDevice.RenderState.CullMode = CullMode.None in XNA 3.x, or GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone in 4.0.

The diagonal line you're seeing down the center of the screen is because you're missing the half-pixel offset to correctly align texels to pixels on screen. Try adding an offset to your vertex positions when you pass them from the vertex shader to the pixel shader like this:

Position.x -= 1.0 / ViewportSize.x;

Position.y += 1.0 / ViewportSize.y;

Where ViewportSize contains the pixel dimensions of your viewport, (1024,768) for example.